# How to get date without time in existing momentjs object?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Let's say I have momentjs object like the following:

```
var date = moment(new Date(2014,2,17,9,60));
```

How could I get clone and get new momentjs object without time?

Comment: You want to clone the existing momentjs object, but without time? Like instantiating a new object?

Comment: yes exaclty. I need to get a new object based on date object

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With moment version 1.7 and above, just use startOf method.

```
var date2 = date1.clone().startOf('day');
```

See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/

Answer (score 5):

The momentjs object will always store a time, regardless of whether you use it. However, the following will clone `date` to `date2` and reset the time:

```
var date2 = date.clone().hour(0).minute(0).second(0).millisecond(0)
```

You'll now have two independent momentjs objects `date` and `date2`

Comment: Is there a way to make it shorter?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a shortcut to set multiple time units at once so this is as short as it can be.

Comment: Is there a reason why the length of the statement needs to be shorter? If you wanted, you could create a plugin that does the time reset that you could then call from one function on the momentjs object

Comment: np. I may use your snippet I just thought that there is better :)

Answer (score 3):

You also can do this as follows.

```
moment().format('LL');  // September 02, 2020
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');  // 2020-09-02
```