# How i can get default date if more than 6 hours have passed?

Tags: momentjs

How i can get default date if more than 6 hours have passed?
how i get relative time

```
let date = 24-05-2021 13:55
const relativeTime = moment(date, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm').fromNow()
```

I saw examples but I can't figure it out, my English is very bad

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333425/add-a-duration-to-a-moment-moment-js then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758345/how-to-get-date-without-time-in-existing-momentjs-object ?

Comment: Can you explain better your problem?

Comment: Thanks for help, I wrote how I solved it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I solved the problem like this, if someone needs a solution.

```
 const date = data.date
 let dateNow = moment(new Date(), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm')
    let postDate = moment(date, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm')
    let result = dateNow.diff(postDate, 'hours')
    console.log(result)
    if (result <= 6) {
       /*if less than 6 hours have passed i return relative date format 2 hours ago*/
      const relativeTime = moment(date, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm').fromNow()
      data.date = relativeTime
      return { data }
    }else {
    /* if more than 6 hours have passed i return original date format 25-05-2021 14:01*/
    return { data }
    }
```